# Overridden function isn't called when using with statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running code from homework assignments with `open` in them. Trouble is, the students were told not to submit the data they were given and assume we have it - and `open` doesn't look in `sys.path`.

Luckily, I am using `Spyder`, which allows me to choose a script to be executed when initializing a console. I figured I could override `open`, so I defined a new `open` function which calls the original `open` on the absolute path of the files. But when someone uses `with open(...) as ...`, it doesn't work.

I know this may not to a good thing to do, but I can't go over every file in every submitted assignment looking for and replacing the call to `open`...

My code is:

```
old_open = open

def open(*args, **kwrdargs):
    try:
        res = old_open(*args,**kwrdargs)
        return res
    except:
        args= list(args)
        if ('DS1' in args[0]):
            args[0]=DS1
        elif ('DS2_X' in args[0]):
            args[0] = DS2_X
        elif ('DS2_Y' in args[0]):
            args[0] = DS2_Y
        args = tuple(args)
        res = old_open(*args,**kwrdargs)
        return res
```

`DS1`,`DS2_X`, `DS2_Y` contain the absolute path to the files.

When executing:

```
with open('DS1.data', 'r') as f:
```

I get the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DS1.data'

while using:

```
f=open('DS1.data','r')
```

works.

I debugged the code, and when using `with`, my `open` is not called, but when using `f=open(...)`, it is. Why is this happening?

Comment: So the problem is not with the `with` statement. The problem is that the file (`DS1.data`) was not found. Failure of the `with` statement will result in a different exception.

Comment: @skyking I don't follow. Why would the file not be found? the statement which doesn't use `with` works, shouldn't the statment with `with` run the exact same code? `open` will be called again with the absolute path instead of the relative one.

Comment: Have you tried using `with f as ff:` with after the last sample? Have you checked which line that's actually causing the exception?

Comment: The line I posted (with the `with`) is the one causing the exception. I just tried what you told me to and that didn't throw an exception. I tried debugging the code (can't believe that hadn't occurred to me), and the statement using `with` doesn't call my `open`, but the one not using `with` does call my `open`.

Comment: Don't override `open`. It will have unintended consequences that are too many to fit in this box. Use `def my_super_special_open(…):` instead. The future you or any readers or users of your code will thank you.

Comment: @msw there will be no future users of my code. I'm attempting to run over 80 submissions, each containing multiple code files which I have no time to check and try to understand individually. So I need to override `open` so I can check if the code works, instead of looking and replacing every instance of `open`. The code they submit isn't necessarily well-written, and I can't run something to look at all the code files and replace each instance of the word `open`, since the string might appear elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`open` is supposed to return a file-like object, it is that object (ie `f` in the below example) that is supposed to have an `__enter__` and `__exit__`. For example you could write your `with`-statement as:

```
f = open(...)

with f as ...:
    do_something()
```

If you don't return the object returned by `open`, but some own wrapper around the file object you have to wrap these too. But from your description it more look like you don't need that, but rather that you've somewhere didn't return a file. Your `open` should look something like:

```
def open(fname, *args, **kwds):
    for p in sys.path:
        fn = build_filename(p, fname)

        try:
            return _orig_open(fn, *args, **kwds)
        except IOerror as e:
            pass

    return _orig_open(fn, *args, **kwds) # must return file or rais exception
```

Comment: But I _do_ return what `open` returns. I'll edit my post to reflect that (this is what I thought at first, but since it doesn't work, I thought maybe it's `open` that's supposed to somehow have these methods...)

Comment: @user1999728 Then maybe you should show us your solution, there's a few things that could go wrong. For example do you `raise` exception if the file couldn't be opened?